# Split a String by a String

Tags: string, parsing, haskell

I'm trying to construct a lexer analyzer using Haskell and I need to construct a function `f :: String -> String -> (String, String)` which split the input in a tuple of strings. The function need to split by a known String. The known String is always at the start of the String to be parsed.

For example if the String to split is "expression" and the input is "expression rest of String" I need to generate an output ("expression", "rest of String").

I'm trying to avoid using advanced libraries.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: The type doesn't fit the problem. Also, what if the shorter string is not a prefix of the longer one?

Comment: @larsmans I was thinking of making the known string hardcoded, but I could change the type to receive it by parameter. Any help on how to implement this function?

Comment: Isn't that just `f prefix s = (prefix, drop (len prefix) s)`? Or am I missing something? (I'm still missing what happens when the prefix doesn't match -- you say it always does, but then why do you need this function?)

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
f :: String -> String -> [String]

f sep src = f_ src []
  where
    f_ [] acc = [reverse acc]
    f_ (x:xs) acc =
      case stripPrefix sep (x:xs) of
        Nothing  -> f_ xs (x:acc)
        Just rem -> [reverse acc] ++ [sep] ++ f_ rem []
```

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to deal with failure somehow, e.g. by returning a Maybe. You seem also to want to eliminate whitespace at the beginning of the remainder?

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Data.List (stripPrefix)

f :: String -> String -> Maybe String
f prefix = fmap (dropWhile isSpace) . stripPrefix prefix

g :: String -> String -> (String, Maybe String)
g prefix str = (prefix, f prefix str)

h :: String -> String -> Maybe (String, String)
h prefix str = case f prefix str of 
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just rest -> Just (prefix, rest)


-- >>> f "expression" "expression rest of string"
-- Just "rest of string"
-- >>> g "expression" "expression rest of string"
-- ("expression",Just "rest of string")
-- >>> h "expression" "expression rest of string"
-- Just ("expression","rest of string")

-- >>> f "expression" "xpression rest of string"
-- Nothing
-- >>> g "expression" "xpression rest of string"
-- ("expression",Nothing)
-- >>> h "expression" "xpression rest of string"
-- Nothing
```

This is a little like the `string` parser found in most parser libraries with types something like `String -> Parser String` -- it returns the string, if it finds it, but fails if it doesn't. The simplest version comes with ghc and isn't an 'advanced library'

```
 >>> import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
 >>> let apply = readP_to_S 
 >>> apply (string "expression") "expression rest of string"
 [("expression"," rest of string")]
 >>> apply (string "expression") "xpression rest of string"
 []
 >>> let myParser = string "expression" >> skipSpaces
 >>> apply myParser "expression rest of string"
 [((),"rest of string")]
 >>> apply myParser "xpression rest of string"
 []
 >>> let myBetterParser = do {exp <- string "expression" ; skipSpaces ; return exp}
 >>> apply myBetterParser "expression rest of string"
 [("expression","rest of string")]
 >>> apply myBetterParser "xpression rest of string"
 []
```